# Manually detect malware (such as a keylogger)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-8.1, malware

Is there any way to manually detect if malware, specifically a keylogger is installed? Looking for answers on XP, 7 and 8.1.

For example, is there a combination of any of these options that can positively identify the malware:

```
* places to look in the registry
* processes running in Windows Task Manager
* writing an application myself (eg. in Visual Studio) to hook WM_XXX messages
```

I'm looking for technical details to investigate this manually ie. NOT using something like an AV that just reports it. 3rd party tools that technically help identify and track down the presence of the malware might be useful.

UPDATE:
Have discovered [this superuser article](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) which more or less covers what I was looking for. Recommend readers who find this question re-direct to that one.

Comment: Most malware is designed to hide itself.  Which is the reason signature and behavior based software is used to detect it.  If you know what symptoms to look for you can make an good educated guess your infected, but removing the malware by hand,, that isn't something you should attempt to do if your unfamiliar with the process.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys, then type `msconfig` in the line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Select *Startup* tab and disable all the unknown programs
   Then restart your computer.
2. You should also look through the list of the installed programs. So, click Start menu, then *All programs*, try to find there the program that you did not install. Uninstall such programs.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, then select Task Manager in the menu. Select *Processes* tab, scroll the list. Find the process that is called winlogon.exe. One process with such a name is a normal thing, but if you have two processes with the same name, then you have a keylogger.
   Highlight the second winlogon.exe and click *End process* (you should end only the second process with such a name). If the above steps don't work, then Malwarebytes anti-malware software will surely help you out.

Comment: Some of the other questions on SU also recommend a utility written by Microsoft called `Autoruns`. This little application is *amazing*, well worth a look. Autoruns finds things that, while not malicious, are often unwanted leftovers from previously installed software or bloatware / "fast startup" type services.